# How does the SPF4J Java Profiler write buffered metrics to files?

Tags: java, profiler, spf4j

I wrote a simple test to capture timing metrics using the [SPF4J](https://www.spf4j.org/) (Simple Profiler Framework For Java) MeasurementRecorder. I'm running a simple for loop and capturing time of a random sleep from 100-200 ms as shown in the complete code sample below.

When I run the test, the Time-Series DataBase (TSDB) files are created successfully, but they're empty while the test is running (around 2 mins). The buffered data are written to files when the application completes, but samples at the end are missing and the last one is truncated, like the buffer is not getting flushed properly.

If the application never terminates (e.g. web service), when will the buffered metrics be written to file - on a timer, or when a certain amount of data is buffered? Is this configurable and, if so, how?

```java
package com.examples.spf4j;

import org.spf4j.perf.MeasurementRecorder;
import org.spf4j.perf.impl.RecorderFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestMeasurementRecorder {

    @Test
    public void testMeasurementRecorder() throws InterruptedException {
        initialize();
        MeasurementRecorder measurementRecorder = getMeasurementRecorder();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<=1000; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Thread.sleep(100 + random.nextInt(100));
            measurementRecorder.record(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        }
    }

    public static void initialize() {
        String tsDbFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "spf4j-performance-monitor.tsdb2";
        String tsTextFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "spf4j-performance-monitor.txt";
        System.setProperty("spf4j.perf.ms.config", "TSDB@" + tsDbFile + "," + "TSDB_TXT@" + tsTextFile);
    }

    public static MeasurementRecorder getMeasurementRecorder() {
        int sampleTimeMillis = 1000;
        return RecorderFactory.createScalableQuantizedRecorder("response time", "ms", sampleTimeMillis, 10, 0, 40, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the system property: spf4j.perf.ms.periodicFlush=true
to enable the periodic flush.

Comment: I added `System.setProperty("spf4j.perf.ms.periodicFlush", "true");` to my init method and now the binary `.tsdb2` file gets updated according to the rate set in `spf4j.perf.ms.flushIntervalMillis`. How are we supposed to know what system properties are available? Is there a list described somewhere? I couldn't find a comprehensive list anywhere in the docs.

Comment: @DV82XL righ now all the Sys prop library "knobs" are scanned and generated [at](http://www.spf4j.org/spf4j-core/avrodoc.html#/schema/spf4j.perf.ms.MsConfig) will make sure they are easier to find, there is room for improvement in this area...